# Generate large number of random card decks - NumPy

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I need to generate a large number of random poker card decks. Speed is important so everything has to be in numpy matrix form.

I understand I can generate two cards from a deck as follows:

```
np.random.choice(12*4,2, replace=False)
```

How can I execute the same query so that a 2d array is created without a for loop? The difficulty is that each round will need to distribute from the original stack, so replace is only true for rows but False for columns.

I've also tried it with

```
originalDeck=np.arange(1,12*4)
np.random.shuffle(originalDeck)
```

But here as well we would need to generate a 2d array of the originalDeck and then each line? Is this possible?

Comment: How about implement a loopy version to start with?

Comment: There will be over 1m card decks, so a loop is too slow. Speed is very important for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate [`np.random.choice(..., replace=False)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)'s behavior with a trick here based on `argsort/argpartition`. The idea is simple : We create a random array and sort it. The sorted indices thus obtained being unique would resemble `np.random.choice(..., replace=False)`.

Since, we are looking to have a 2D array with such a feature, start with a random 2D array and for performance use [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) for getting the first two sorted indices along each row to simulate `2` cards picking.

Thus, we would have a vectorized approach like so -

```
# N : Number of queries
# M : Number of cards to be picked
out = np.argpartition(np.random.rand(N,12*4),M,axis=1)[:,:M]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [55]: # Input params
    ...: N = 1000000 # Number of queries
    ...: M = 2 # Number of cards to be picked
    ...: 
    ...: def original_app(N,M):
    ...:     out = np.empty((N,2),dtype=int)
    ...:     for i in range(N):
    ...:         out[i] = np.random.choice(12*4,M, replace=False)
    ...:     return out
    ...: 
    ...: def vectorized_app(N,M):
    ...:     return np.argpartition(np.random.rand(N,12*4),M,axis=1)[:,:M]
    ...: 

In [56]: %timeit original_app(N,M)
1 loops, best of 3: 12.7 s per loop

In [57]: %timeit vectorized_app(N,M)
1 loops, best of 3: 678 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only looking for pair of cards, you have only `1128` possible pairs (without replacement), so you could generate all pairs and then pick random cards from this set:

```
from itertools import combinations
# There may be a better way to generate all possible pairs in numpy,
# but I am not aware of and this is pretty fast for this size
all_pairs = np.array(list(combinations(range(12 * 4), 2)))
cards = all_pairs[np.random.randint(all_pairs.shape[0], size = N_PAIRS), :]
```

Where `N_PAIRS` is the number of pairs you want.

Benchmarks:

```
In [55]: # Input params
    ...: N = 1000000 # Number of queries
    ...: M = 2 # Number of cards to be picked
    ...: 
    ...: def original_app(N,M):
    ...:     out = np.empty((N,2),dtype=int)
    ...:     for i in range(N):
    ...:         out[i] = np.random.choice(12*4,M, replace=False)
    ...:     return out
    ...: 
    ...: def vectorized_app(N,M):
    ...:     return np.argpartition(np.random.rand(N,12*4),M,axis=1)[:,:M]
    ...: 
    ...: def itertools_app(N,M):
    ...:     all_pairs = np.array(list(combinations(range(12 * 4), M)))
    ...:     return all_pairs[np.random.randint(all_pairs.shape[0], size = N), :]

In [46]: %timeit original_app(N,M)
1 loops, best of 3: 10.8 s per loop

In [47]: %timeit vectorized_app(N,M)
1 loops, best of 3: 618 ms per loop

In [48]: %timeit itertools_app(N,M)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ms per loop
```

This method is really fast when `M` is very small, as `M` gets bigger, the number of combinations increases exponentially, and thus even creating the `all_pairs` array is not possible (already with `M = 5` you have ~1700000 possible combinations).

Comment: This is not a numpy solution. With lists it's easy but it's very slow.

Comment: @nickpick You only use list to generate the initial set of pairs, which contains only `1128` pairs as mentioned in my post. This is clearly not slow, except if you need to generate it multiple times. If this is the case,  you should add details on exactly what you want to do to your question.

Comment: @nickpick Whatever the solution you choose, you should not always put your faith in a "full numpy" solution. For `N = 1000000` and `M = 2`, the above solution is way faster than the `vectorized_app` proposed by @Divakar

Comment: Not according to his timed post above. He says 12secs vs .7secs

Comment: @nickpick His `original_app` is clearly not my solution.

Comment: Interesting, are you sure your version is faster even though it contains conversions into lists etc?

Comment: @nickpick The "`list` part" is only involved to generate all combinations of 2 cards, which is a relatively small set (1128 pairs). If you try with `M = 3`, it is still faster, but as `M` increase, you cannot store the set of pairs in memory (or even if you can, it is slow), so @Divakar version is better for "big" M (I did not test all values).

Comment: Ok interesting to see. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK `np.random.randint()`, doesn't guarantee unique elements, so even when we index it with `all_pairs[]` (which has unique elements), it won't guarantee unique numbers after indexing. So, won't that be not following the `replace=False` criteria set in the question?

Comment: @Divakar `randint` is used to generate indexes for the pairs, not the card themselves. The `replace=False` criteria is maintained by the combinations (`itertools.combinations` default behavior is to not generate combinations with replacement). You will obviously get identical pairs in the final results (there is no way to get `1000000` different pairs from `48` cards).

Comment: @Holt Hmm that makes sense I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Giving it another look, you can avoid the lists and combinations for a simple one and hopefully much more efficient way with : `np.column_stack((np.triu_indices(48,1)))` to give us `all_pairs`.

Comment: @Divakar For `M = 2`, there is no difference between the `itertools.combinations` and `np.column_stack` version (on my computer). Is it possible to use the `np.column_stack` version for `M > 2`?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, might be some convoluted way. I could think of using a 3D array for that to get those all_pairs indices, but with such heavy datasize might not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

A another simple approach, slightly slower than @Holt best solution.

```
def vectorized_app(N):
    u=np.random.randint(0,12*4,(2*N*103//100)).reshape(-1,2) # 3% more tries. 
    w=np.not_equal(*u.T) #selecting valid output, Two differents cards.
    return u[w][:N]
```