# Time performance of np.random.permutation, np.random.choice

Tags: python, numpy, random

I encountered a function with very poor time performance relative to comparable MATLAB code in my pure python graph theory library, so I attempted to profile some operations in this function.

I tracked it to the following result

```
In [27]: timeit.timeit( 'permutation(138)[:4]', setup='from numpy.random import permutation', number=1000000)
Out[27]: 27.659916877746582
```

Compared this to the performance in MATLAB

```
>> tic; for i=1:1000000; randperm(138,4); end; toc
Elapsed time is 4.593305 seconds.
```

I was able to considerably improve performance by changing this to `np.random.choice` instead of `np.random.permutation` as I had originally wrote.

```
In [42]: timeit.timeit( 'choice(138, 4)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=1000000)
Out[42]: 18.9618501663208
```

But it still doesn't nearly approach the matlab performance.

Is there another way of obtaining this behavior in pure python with time performance approaching the MATLAB time performance?

Comment: Don't forget, you need to pass `replace=False` to `np.random.choice` if you want a sample without replacement. (Not a performance improvement, but it is an important fix for correctness.)

Comment: `numpy.random.choice` has a long standing performance issue for such a use case, see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How long does this take for you? I estimate 1-2 seconds.

```
def four():
    k = np.random.randint(138**4)
    a = k % 138
    b = k // 138 % 138
    c = k // 138**2 % 138
    d = k // 138**3 % 138
    return (a, b, c, d) if a != b and a != c and a != d and b != c and b != d and c != d else four()
```

**Update 1:** At first I used `random.randrange`, but `np.random.randint` made the whole thing about twice as fast.

**Update 2:** Since NumPy's random function appears to be much faster, I tried this and it's another factor ~1.33 faster:

```
>>> def four():
        a = randint(138)
        b = randint(138)
        c = randint(138)
        d = randint(138)
        return (a, b, c, d) if a != b and a != c and a != d and b != c and b != d and c != d else four()

>>> import timeit
>>> from numpy.random import randint
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: four(), number=1000000)
2.3742770821572776
```

That's about 22 times faster than the original:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('permutation(138)[:4]', setup='from numpy.random import permutation', number=1000000)
51.80568455893672
```

(string vs `lambda` doesn't make a noticeable difference)

Comment: This implementation does not beat MATLAB's speed but it is within 10%.

Comment: @aestrivex Try the updated version, I'm using NumPy's random function now and it's twice as fast for me.

Comment: I did some more testing myself and found that `np.random.randint` is faster than the `random.randrange` function. My profiling did not suggest that repeatedly calling `randint(n)` four times was better than `randint(n**4)`, actually the latter was slightly better.

Comment: @aestrivex Hmm, interesting. Did you compare my above solutions exactly as they are, or did you make modifications? For example it makes a big difference whether you use `numpy.random.randint` or `randint`.

Comment: I made modifications and tried several different implementations, but exactly your code currently listed at the top of your answer using `np.random.randint(n**4)` gives the best time performance, about 75% faster than calling `np.random.randint(n)` four times.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572771/3293881) that showed how one can simulate [`np.random.choice(..., replace=False)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)'s behavior with a trick based on `argsort`/`argpartition`, you can recreate MATLAB's `randperm(138,4)`, i.e. NumPy's `np.random.choice(138,4, replace=False)` with [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) as :

```
np.random.rand(138).argpartition(range(4))[:4]
```

Or with [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) like so -

```
np.random.rand(138).argsort()[:4]
```

Let's time these two versions for performance comparison against the MATLAB version.

On MATLAB -

```
>> tic; for i=1:1000000; randperm(138,4); end; toc
Elapsed time is 1.058177 seconds.
```

On NumPy with `np.argpartition` -

```
In [361]: timeit.timeit( 'np.random.rand(138).argpartition(range(4))[:4]', setup='import numpy as np', number=1000000)
Out[361]: 9.063489798831142
```

On NumPy with `np.argsort` -

```
In [362]: timeit.timeit( 'np.random.rand(138).argsort()[:4]', setup='import numpy as np', number=1000000)
Out[362]: 5.74625801707225
```

The original proposed one with NumPy -

```
In [363]: timeit.timeit( 'choice(138, 4)', setup='from numpy.random import choice', number=1000000)
Out[363]: 6.793723535243771
```

Seems like one could use `np.argsort` for a marginal performance improvement.

Comment: Seems pretty flawed. I tried it a million times with 5 and 3 instead of 138 and 4. Out of the 60 possible outcomes, 27 **never** occurred, 3 occurred about 100000 times, 12 occurred about 33333 times, and 18 occurred about 16667 times.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Could you share the codes that you used for that investigation? Thanks!

Comment: @Divakar `collections.Counter(tuple(np.random.rand(5).argpartition(3)[:3]) for _ in range(1000000)).most_common()`

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thank you so much for testing all that! So, as it turns out argpartiton with that `kth` option being a scalar produces some bias. So, replaced that with a range that sorts all at once and thus creates an unbiased distribution as stated in its [`docs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). So, your worry of not being a uniform distri. should be fixed in the edits. Thanks again!

Comment: @Divakar Try storing `np.arange(4)` in a variable during setup and using it as the `kth` parameter instead of `range(4)`. More than doubles the speed for me. (My own answer is still over five times faster for me, though :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yeah that `range` has to be pretty slow, so `np.arange` should boost it up! Thanks!