# random flip m values from an array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have an array with length `n`, I want to randomly choose `m` elements from it and flip their value. What is the most efficient way?

there are two cases, `m=1` case is a special case. It can be discussed separately, and `m=/=1`.

My attempt is:

```
import numpy as np
n = 20
m = 5
#generate an array a
a = np.random.randint(0,2,n)*2-1
#random choose `m` element and flip it.
for i in np.random.randint(0,n,m):
    a[m]=-a[m]
```

Suppose `m` are tens and `n` are hundreds.

Comment: Define efficient. Also what are the approximate values of n and m? The most efficient method for some values, may not be the most efficient for others.

Comment: @cammil See the edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make sure we are not flipping the same element twice or even more times, we can create unique indices in that length range with [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) using its optional `replace` argument set as False. Then, simply indexing into the input array and flipping in one go should give us the desired output. Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
idx = np.random.choice(n,m,replace=False)
a[idx] = -a[idx]
```

**Faster version :** For a faster version of `np.random_choice`, I would suggest reading up on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572771/3293881) that explores using `np.argpartition` to simulate identical behavior.

Comment: `random.choice` verses `idx = np.random.randint(0,n,m)` prevent I choose generate same element. Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a random permutation of the array indices, take the first `m` of them and flip their values:

```
a[np.random.permutation(range(len(a)))[:m]]*=-1
```

Using `permutation` validate you don't choose the same index twice.

Comment: Will these operation have different index on the left and right side? I mean: if we do `a[random.randint()]=-a[random.randint()]`, probably we are not doing the task because on the right side `random.randint()` will run second time thus change the index.  If we do `a[random.randint()] *= -1` does the `random.randint()` only run one time?

Comment: The `randint` will run just one time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the index of the array from `m` to `i` to actually change the value.
Result:

```py
import numpy as np
n = 20
m = 5
#generate an array a
a = np.random.randint(0,2,n)*2-1
print(a)
#random choose `i` element and flip it.
for i in np.random.randint(0,n,m):
    a[i] = -a[i]

print(a)
```

My output:

```
[ 1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1]
[ 1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1]
```