# Take repeated sample of a list

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a list `range(n)` and want to take a random sample of `r` without replacing, i.e. `np.random.choice(n,r, replace = False)`. But I want to do this often, is there a fast way for the following command:

```
a = [np.random.choice(n,r,replace = False) for i in range(100)]
```

Note: `n` and `r` can be "large", s.t. `a = np.random.choice(n,(r,100), replace = True)` and removing the ones that have two similar indexes will be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick I have often used to replace iterations of `np.random.choice(..., replace=False)` is generating `2D` array of random numbers and then using `argsort/argpartition` to get unique integers numbers.

Thus, with `argsort`, it would be -

```
np.random.rand(100,n).argsort(axis=1)[:,:r]
```

Alternatively, with `r` being a relatively smaller number than `n`, we would use `argpartition` for performance boost, like so -

```
np.argpartition(np.random.rand(100,n),r, axis=1)[:,:r]
```