# How to generate bounded random array based on mean and standard deviation of another array?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have an array `X` containing `R` rows and `C` columns. I wish to generate a new array named `a_array` where each element will be randomly generated based on the mean and standard deviation of its corresponding row in `X`. What is the most pythonic and efficient way to do this using Numpy?

Currently, I am using a nested loop to generate element-wise numbers.

```
a_array = np.zeros(shape=(a_size, X.shape[0]))
for i in range(a_size):
    for j in range(X.shape[0]):
        a_array[i][j] = np.random.randint(low=X[i].mean()-X[i].std(), high=X[i].mean()+X[i].std())
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot something but I would also like to ensure that each row of a_array contains unique elements (There are no duplicate elements in any row). I have not been able to think of any way to achieve this till now.

Comment: Can you please include sample data of what `X` contains?

Comment: X contains positive integers.

Comment: Ok. So `X` and `a_array` both are two dimensional arrays.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Partially vectorized

We could reduce it to one loop -

```
m,s = X[:a_size].mean(1),X[:a_size].std(1)
L = (m-s).astype(int)
H = (m+s).astype(int)
out = np.empty((a_size,X.shape[0]),dtype=int)
for i,(l,h) in enumerate(zip(L,H)):
    out[i] = np.random.choice(np.arange(l,h),X.shape[0],replace=False)
```

Basic idea :

1. Compute mean and std values along the second axis. Before that, we need to slice `X` to limit it to `a_size` rows, if `a_size` isn't the number of rows in `X`.
2. In the original loopy version, we are using `random.randint` with mean-std and mean+std as the limits. So, for the proposed version, get the low and high limits using mean and std values from step#1.
3. Run a loop with `np.random.choice(np.arange(l,h),X.shape[0],replace=False)` with those low and high values for setting the range of values to choose from and select random values of size `X.shape[0]` and unique ones with `replace=False`.

#### Fully vectorized

We could make it fully vectorized with a trick as listed in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438143/) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50447535/) to give us something like the following that replaces the loopy step listed earlier :

```
R = H-L
MX = R.max()
n = X.shape[0]
unqIDs = np.random.rand(len(L),MX).argpartition(axis=1,kth=n)[:,:n]
out = unqIDs%R[:,None] + L[:,None]
```

Note that this would have more memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for something like this. Can you please explain how the last line works? Also, by any chance is there a possibility to ensure that all elements in each row are unique in a_array?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot asking the unique part. I have added it as an edit. Will it be possible to answer that as well?

Comment: Thanks, this solves it unless even this loop can be removed.

Comment: This is great. Amazing answer! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just remove a level of the for loop and generate a vector of random numbers to replace the entire row versus replacing on position at a time

```
a_array = np.zeros(shape=(a_size, X.shape[0]))
for i in range(a_size):
    a_array[i] = np.random.randint(\
                      low=X[i].mean()-X[i].std(),\ 
                      high=X[i].mean()+X[i].std(),\
                      size=(1,a_array.shape[1]))
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot asking the unique part. I have added it as an edit. Will it be possible to answer that as well?