# Numpy random choice with probabilities to produce a 2D-array with unique rows

Tags: python, numpy

Similar to [Numpy random choice to produce a 2D-array with all unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437988/numpy-random-choice-to-produce-a-2d-array-with-all-unique-values), I am looking for an efficient way of generating:

```
n = 1000
k = 10
number_of_combinations = 1000000

p = np.random.rand(n)
p /= np.sum(p)

my_combinations = np.random.choice(n, size=(number_of_combinations, k), replace=False, p=p)
```

As discussed in the previous question, I want this matrix to have only unique rows. Unfortunately, the [provided solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437988/numpy-random-choice-to-produce-a-2d-array-with-all-unique-values) do not work for the additional extension of using specific probabilities p.

My current solution is as follows:

```
my_combinations = set()

while len(my_combinations) < number_of_combinations:
    new_combination = np.random.choice(n, size=k, replace=False, p=p)
    my_combinations.add(frozenset(new_combination))

print(my_combinations)
```

However, I do think that there should be a more efficient numpy approach to solve this faster.

Answer (score 2):

For these parameter values, the probability of encountering a duplicate row is astronomically small (unless `p` is very skewed, perhaps to the extent that cannot be accommodated by float precision). I would just use

```
my_combinations = np.random.choice(n, size=number_of_combinations, k), replace=True, p=p)
```

You can check for duplicates in `O(N log N)` where `N = number_of_combinations`;

Conservatively, you could generate

`my_combinations = np.random.choice(n, size=2 * number_of_combinations, k), replace=True, p=p)`

then [drop duplicates](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) and take the first `number_of_combinations` rows.